# sqlparse.format(altertable_translate(i), reindent=True, keyword_case='upper') + "\n\n"

Tags: visual-studio-code

sqlparse.format(altertable_translate(i), reindent=True, keyword_case='upper') + "\n\n"

SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
procedure_re = re.compile("(create\s+(?:or\s+replace\s+)?procedure\s+)(.*?)(END_PROC\s*;)",

Comment: Finding this error can anybody explain this